# Expo project fails to build when using expo-secure-store SDK

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, es6-modules

I have filed an issue in the repo here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20089 but a lot of these bug reports are not being reviewed

I cannot add the expo-secure-store plugin to my expo development build without it failing. This happens for a very simple straight out of the box development build with expo-secure-store as the only plugin

#### Environment

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Linux 5.15 Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 16.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/bin/yarn
npm: 7.24.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/npm
npmPackages:
expo: ~47.0.6 => 47.0.6
react: 18.1.0 => 18.1.0
react-native: 0.70.5 => 0.70.5
npmGlobalPackages:
eas-cli: 2.4.0
expo-cli: 6.0.6
Expo Workflow: managed
```

#### Minimal reproducible example

Snack https://snack.expo.dev/@seanbarker6/expo-secure-store

1. Create new expo project

```
npx create-expo-app my-app

cd my-app

npx expo install expo-dev-client
```

2. Set up EAS build. My eas build was for android

```
eas build:configure
```

3. Install expo-secure-store and add to config

```
npx expo install expo-secure-store
```

**app.json**

```json
    {
      "expo": {
    ...
        "plugins": [
          "expo-secure-store"
        ]
      }
    }
```

4. Run `npx expo prebuild` or `eas build --profile development --platform android`. This results in the following error

```
CommandError: Package "expo-secure-store" does not contain a valid config plugin.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin

Cannot use import statement outside a module
```